# Razor pages problem with pass value mediator

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, mediator

It is my .cshtml

```
        <label asp-for="CreateAccount.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="CreateAccount.Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CreateAccount.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
```

here is cshtml.cs

```
[BindProperty]
public CreateAccountCommand CreateAccount { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(CreateAccountCommand command)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _mediator.Send(command);
   }
    else
   {

   }
    return Page();
}
```

This is CreateAccountCommand

```
public class CreateAccountCommand : IRequest
{
public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And here is CreateAccountHandler

```
public class CreateAccountHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateAccountCommand, Unit>
{
private readonly YourMeetingDbContext _dbContext;

public CreateAccountHandler(YourMeetingDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateAccountCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = new ApplicationUser
    {
        Email = request.Email,
    }; 
}
```

How can I pass a value to CreateAccountHandler and created new ApplicationUser with Email value ? If I trying now, public string Email { get; set; }  takes a value Email, but if I call await _mediator.Send (command) this Email is empty.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "*pass a value to CreateAccountHandler*", the `CreateAccountCommand` should contain all the required data for it to work, if you need more data, add it to that command.

Comment: your `Email` is empty because you get it from a model that is not bound at all. Try changing this `_mediator.Send(command)` to `_mediator.Send(CreateAccount)`. Your `OnPostAsync` handler does not need a parameter for model binding because you bind your model via the property `CreateAccount`.

Comment: As King said, since you are using Razor page Model Binding, you could directly get the value from the CreateAccount property. If you want to submit the form and use the parameters in the Razor Page handler method, you could refer to [this tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages-Form-Submit-Post-Example.aspx). About calling the CreateAccountHandler, try to use [Dependency injection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#disposal-of-services) to register the methods, then, call the method from razor page.